# Location tracking is not working in GPS

Tags: java, android, gps

I am facing a problem in the process of location tracking. When I track locations via the network provider it works but when I turn on the GPS it shows the error `java.lang.NullPointerException` at this line in my GPS tracker class:

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Are there any conditions to solve?

**GPS tracker.java:**

```
if (isGPSEnabled) {
    if (location == null) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Log.i("location gpsssssssssssss", location.toString());
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the mylocationlistener class:

```
GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(mylocationlistener.this);
if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
    latiude = gps.getLatitude();
    String lat=String.valueOf(latiude);
    String longi=String.valueOf(longitude);
    Log.v("lat", lat);
    Log.v("longi", longi);
    Log.v("sededededed", "--=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-");
    longitude = gps.getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: Post your code then...

Comment: You say that the `NullPointerException` is thrown in the line `location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(...)`, right? Have you added the null check since or is that already part of the failing code? And have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `locationManager` object is **null** thats why it throws `NullPointerException`

Comment: what is the reason for null value only in gps. @Sanket